# Teamcity VCS problem

Tags: контроль-версий, gitlab, teamcity

Доброго времени суток.
Существует проект, у него настроен VCS. Связан с локальным gitlab.
У VCS Authentication method: Password. Логин и пароль пользователя заведенного на gitlab. Все работало. 
Понадобилось изменить пароль для этого пользователя.
Теперь в teamcity пишет следующее сообщение:

> Failed for the root 'git: maplet' #213: List remote refs failed:
>   org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: http://local/our.git:
>   git-upload-pack not permitted

Как исправить эту ошибку?
Пользователь тот же самый, права не менялись, изменили только пароль.

Comment: буквально вчера сталкнулся с этой проблемой. помог мне работа с гитлабом по ssh. у них есть баг на этот случай